# DictionaryLoopkup - pattern specification

Tags: core-language

I would like to find all Italian words that have a specific pattern of letter repetitions.

Actually I'm looking for 6-letters words that have 1 letter repeated 3 times, a second letter repeated two times and another letter repeated 1 time.

I see that I should use:

```
DictionaryLookup[{"Italian", pattern}]
```

but I'm not much familiar with patterns and I don't know how to tell Mathematica to choose the words with above letters multiplicity specification.

[BTW, one of these words should be "Pioppo" (italian word for the tree "Poplar")]

I'm rather sure there must be some very simple solutions.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given pattern the following solution is about twice as fast as kguler's StringCount/DeleteDuplicates method (however it does scale worse than kguler's):

```
DictionaryLookup[{"Italian", #}] & /@ 
   Permutations[StringExpression[a_, b_, b_, c_, c_, c_]] // Flatten
```

> {"banana", "cavava", "datata", "lavava", "patata", 
>   "scocco", "stette", "cimici", "cinici", "civici", "dividi", "madama", 
>   "minimi", "rimiri", "ritiri", "tarata", "temete", "tenete", "vagava", 
>   "varava", "popolo", "amammo", "acceca", "errare", "errore", "errerà", 
>   "errerò", "orrore", "orrori", "gregge", "pioppo", "scassa", "scosso", 
>   "smesse", "smosso", "spesse", "stesse", "tratta", "trotto", "adatta", 
>   "avalla", "elegge", "elette", "emette", "eresse", "erette", "estese", 
>   "pioppi", "abbaia", "accada", "accasa", "affama", "allaga", "ammala", 
>   "annata", "appaga", "appaia", "ebbene", "eccede", "essere", "irrisi", 
>   "irriti", "vivevi", "acacia", "ananas", "caccia", "bibbia", "bibbie"}

Originally I came up with the more elegant

```
DictionaryLookup[{"Italian", 
  Permutations[StringExpression[a_, b_, b_, c_, c_, c_]]}] // Flatten
```

but it seems that `DictionaryLookup` doesn't handle string patterns with alternatives correctly.

Answer (score 4):

> *6-letters words that have 1 letter repeated 3 times, a second letter repeated two times and another letter repeated 1 time*

```
condF = With[{pat = #}, StringLength[pat] == 6 && 
           (Sort[StringCount[pat, #] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[Characters[pat]]] == {1, 2, 3})] &;

DictionaryLookup[{"Italian", pat : (__) /; (condF@pat)}]
(* {"abbaia","acacia","accada","accasa","acceca","adatta","affama",
"allaga","amammo","ammala","ananas","annata","appaga","appaia",
"avalla","banana","bibbia","bibbie","caccia","cavava","cimici",
"cinici","civici","datata","dividi","ebbene","eccede","elegge",
"elette","emette","eresse","erette","errare","errerà","errerò",
"errore","essere","estese","gregge","irrisi","irriti","lavava",
"madama","minimi","orrore","orrori","patata","pioppi","pioppo",
"popolo","rimiri","ritiri","scassa","scocco","scosso","smesse",
"smosso","spesse","stesse","stette","tarata","temete","tenete",
"tratta","trotto","vagava","varava","vivevi"}*)
```

The ones starting with `"p"`:

```
DictionaryLookup[{"Italian", pat : ("p" ~~ __) /; (condF@pat)}]
(* {"patata","pioppi","pioppo","popolo"} *)
```

Comment: `condF = With[{pat = #}, StringLength[pat] == 6 && Sort[Tally[Characters[pat]][[All, 2]]] == {1, 2, 3}] &;` is about 25% faster

Comment: @Sjoerd, shorter / more elegant too. Perhaps that should also be posted as an answer? (I am hoping that someone will also post an answer that uses a regex pattern.)

Comment: @kguler wonderful! Thanks! And what If I would find, between these words, the ones that have the maximum number of meaningful anagrams?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries even better! Thanks!

Comment: @LucaM, i suggest you wait for a few days before you accept an answer. Questions with accepted answers tend to get less attention, and, in particular, questions related to string patterns tend to get answers over several days.

Comment: @kguler ok, I understand your point and I've removed the accepted answer flag (I just didn't want to run the risk to forget...)